# Instance of Complex Double

Tags: class, haskell, types, instance, complex-numbers

I'm writing a class `Separate` which performs certain operations independently on "parts" of different structures; e.g. the real and complex parts of a complex number (later I'll also need it for lists). In this way I can write functions that don't care which of these structures they're acting on but will do it in this independent way.

The functions should work normally on structures without parts, e.g. `Double`.

This will be used among other things to compute standard deviations (I know there is a standard deviation defined for complex numbers that gives a real number but the "independent" one makes more sense in my case).

But I'm having trouble with some instance declarations. In particular one of the operations should be "multiply with a `Double`", aka `scale`:

```
class Separate a where
  scale :: Double -> a -> a

instance Separate Double where
  scale = (*)

instance (Floating a) => Separate (Complex a) where
  d `scale` z = (*d) <$> z
```

This of course doesn't compile because `*` isn't defined between a `Double` and a general `Floating a`. But I can't define directly `instance Separate (Complex Double) where...`.

I could just write a function `Double -> Complex Double -> Complex Double` with no class but then the standard deviation must be defined separately for different structures.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just use FlexibleInstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As n.m. points out, defining `instance Separate (Complex Double)` is perfectly fine if you use the `FlexibleInstances` extension, which is a popular and harmless extension.

But there are other options, too, for example:

```
instance (Floating a) => Separate (Complex a) where
    d `scale` z = (* realToFrac d) <$> z
```

And the compositional instance *([the best kind of instance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo))*:

```
instance (Separate a) => Separate (Complex a) where
    d `scale` z = (d `scale`) <$> z
```

Comment: Nice! I like the last option. But why doesn't the compiler complain about this; it can't know that scale is defined fir a given a (e.g. Int)? Will it complan if you use it in a context later where this can happen? I should probably read up on compositional instances..

Comment: @jorgen Notice the `(Separate a) =>` clause, which guarantees that `scale` is defined for `a`.  This instance says `Complex` *preserves* `Separate`ness.

Comment: Ah, makes sense

Comment: @VanessaMcHale [works for me](https://repl.it/KszN/0), what error are you getting/expecting?

Comment: @VanessaMcHale oh you wrote the other answer.  Application binds tighter than operator sections, too.  Just as `2 * realToFrac d` is parsed as `2 * (realToFrac d)`, `(* realToFrac d)` is parsed as `(* (realToFrac d))`.  I suspect you may come from the lisp world where that syntax would mean something quite different.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *type* issue rather than an issue with how you are handling instances. As you say, `(*)` is not defined between a `Double` and a `Float`. However, we can easily convert between a `Double` and a `Float`, so you're in luck! With [`realToFrac`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:realToFrac), we can convert between various fractional types.

I would rewrite the instance as follows:

```
instance (Floating a) -> Separate (Complex a) where
  d `scale` z = (* (realToFrac d)) <$> z
```